# how to change MTU inside docker container on ubuntu 14.4

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, docker, ubuntu-14.04

I want to change *MTU(Maximum Transmission Unit)* inside `docker` which is running on ubuntu 14.04. Also docker container running with ubuntu 14.04.

The problem is that its `docker0` interface on host os can change the MTU value from 1500 to 9000 but its doesn't gives affects inside docker os. means inside docker it is running with a older value i.e 1500. And when I restart the docker services on host machine its all changes goes to default.

I had also tried with creating bridge connection with new interface but while I up that interface its down my whole network and doesn't work anymore.

Help will be highly appreciated

Comment: see https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#docker0

Comment: Thank you @user2915097 by editing /etc/default/docker with MTU value worked in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#docker0 extract "

```
--mtu=BYTES — override the maximum packet length on docker0.
```

On Ubuntu you would add these to the DOCKER_OPTS setting in /etc/default/docker on your Docker host and restarting the Docker service."